# Access Denied in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a one line PowerShell script, when it executes it gives me a total site list of IIS server, but when I save to an Excel spreadsheet I get an Access denied error.

Code:

```
cmd /c  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > c:\sites.xls
```

Log 1:

```
Access to the path 'C:\sites.xls' is denied.
At line:1 char:53
+ cmd /c  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > <<<<  c:\sites.xls
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure
```

Log 2:

```
+  cmd /c  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > <<<<  %temp%\sites.xls 
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure
```

How I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

The output of the command is being output to a file in a location where the current user does not have access to write a file. Try outputting the file to a location where the user has access. For example:

```
cmd /c  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > %temp%\sites.xls
```

Alternatively, if the file MUST be output to `c:\`, then try running the Powershell process as a user with permissions to that folder (e.g. start -> type 'powershell' -> right-click 'Windows Powershell', and choose 'Run as Administrator'. Then try with the original command line:

```
cmd /c  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site > c:\sites.xls
```

Comment: Please find Log 2 in my post

Comment: If you type `$env:temp` in Powershell, you should get the location of the temporary directory for the current user (assuming that the user environment variable `TEMP` is defined). Ensure that the current user (check with `$env:username`) has access to the directory and file that you wish to output to. Here's an overview of how to set access control permissions: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7